# Facing issue with ng-init for dynamic data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, meteor

ng-init with dynamic data is not working

Below is my html with the select field in div.

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-lg-4">
<select name="trader" class="form-control" id="select" ng-model="$root.customerDetails.traderType" 
ng-init="$ctrl.initi()" ng-options="traderTypeObj.description for traderTypeObj in traderTypes 
track by traderTypeObj.type" >
</select>
</div>
```

Now I need to display the first option in the select field by default which I get from a service.So Iam using ng-init.But it is not working .So Iam trying to call a function from ng-init.

If I set this `$rootScope.customerDetails.traderType=$scope.traderTypes[1];`  the  will display the first option by default.I tested this by taking a button and setting that onclick and its working.So now I tried to call that fuction using ng-init and using $scope.$apply()

```
this.initi=function(){
$rootScope.customerDetails.traderType = $scope.traderTypes[1];
$scope.$apply();
};
```

When first time it loads giving the html as error and from second time it is giving `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress`

The issue is Iam calling the value before the ajax service is being called ...

How can I get that option being set..Can please someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
   this.initi=function(){
     $timeout(function() {
       $rootScope.customerDetails.traderType = $scope.traderTypes[1];   
       $scope.$apply();
    })
    };
```

Comment: Getting this error

angular_angular.js:12545 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

Comment: on changing !$scope to !$rootScope error disappeared...But default value is not getting set

Comment: can you try this, $timeout(function(){
$rootScope.customerDetails.traderType = $scope.traderTypes[1];
  $scope.$apply();
});

Comment: After tring the above giving this error
angular_angular.js?hash=744f2a2…:12545 TypeError: v2.initi is not a function

Comment: This is what I have given for function.Is there anything wrong
    this.initi= $timeout(
    function()
    { $rootScope.customerDetails.traderType = $scope.traderTypes[1];  $scope.$apply();
     }
   );

Comment: Didnt worked..giving this error
angular_angular.js?hash=744f2a2…:12545 TypeError: Cannot set property 'traderType' of undefined

Comment: it means traderType does not have value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129206/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-h-varma).

Answer (score 0):

try this html

```
  <div class="form-group" ng-init="init()">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
  <select name="trader" class="form-control" id="select" ng-model="cus_traderType" ng-options="traderTypeObj.description for traderTypeObj in traderTypes 
 track by traderTypeObj.type" >
       </select>
        </div>
```

app.js code

please set $scope.cus_traderType  your main controller
like this

```
$scope.cus_traderType = '';
$scope.init=function(){

 $scope.cus_traderType = $scope.traderTypes[1];

 };
```